# Using the new keyword

Tags: c#, new-operator

I am slightly confused about when to use New. What is the difference between this two statements:

```
List<myObject> myData = GetDataFromDatabase(id);
```

and

```
List<myObject> myData = new List<myObject>();
myData = GetDataFromDatabase(id);
```

For the second usage Resharper gives me this warning:

> Local variable myData is only assigned but its value is never used

The return type of `GetDataFromDatabase(id)` is `List(Of myObject)`.

Thanks

Comment: actually no need to createa new list object again because any how your method `GetDataFromDatabase(id)` might already be written in such a manner that it returns a `List`. So in your case you are first initializing the myData object with new list and then replacing that with new list which is returned by the method `GetDataFromDatabase(id)`. So the better practice might be either initialize with null and get the value from the method and assign to your variable directly or the other way of doing is to directly while creating the variable itself call the method which you have shown in firstcase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `new` when **you** create a new instance of an object.
If you call a method that returns an instance, it used the `new` instead of you.

For example:

```
List<myObject> myData = GetDataFromDatabase(id)

List<myObject> GetDataFromDatabase(int id)
{
    // Here "they" used the new keyword.
    return new List<myObject>();        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `new` to instantiate an object.

The call to `GetDataFromDatabase` returns an object and it is up to that function to either instantiate a new object, or return an existing one.

The warning from Resharper is accurate. Your second block of code instantiates a new object and stores a reference to that new object in `myData`:

```
List<myObject> myData = new List<myObject>();
```

Your code then immediately loses that reference by replacing it with whatever is returned from the function call:

```
myData = GetDataFromDatabase(id);
```

In other words the first line, the one that used `new` is pointless and should not be present.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you create a new object.
You than change the refrence of myData to another object (Created by the method)
and so the object you have created has no refrences to it and it will be removed from memory in the next garbage collection cycle. So in short, the second example makes no sense.
Why create a new object if you do not use it?

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword assigns memory for an object and returns a reference to the object, so you can use it. If you call a method and this method returns a reference to an object, you don't need to allocate memory for this object.

Answer (score 0):

The new keyword is used if you create a `New` Instance of an object. without knowing what the method `GetDataFromDatabase` does i am assuming that it is returning a list which is why you can instantiate a new list with the use of a method call.

So that the new list that will be created will be a copy of the list returned by the method.

In short the new keyword is used to create a new instance of an object. Some call this a has-a relationship with an other class.

Answer (score 0):

If the `GetDataFromDatabase` function returns new instance of `List<myObject>` you don't actually need to create `new List<myObject>();` and then `GetDataFromDatabase(id);`

When using the `new` keyword you're asking to create a new instance of `List<myObject>`, but when you use `myData = GetDataFromDatabase(id);` you're crating a new one and the GC will collect the previous one

Answer (score 0):

The reshaper just tells you, that you put values into the list, but you don't do anything with the values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all answer. i will try gave a best example according to with some interesting point of view programmer.

some point of the New Operator

1. A new operator work on a when our program "RUN TIME " condition. The compiler create a instance of the run time environment.
2. if we call a any class of method, compiler will be check of the instance a class.
3. We have many instance of a create any class.
4. The new operator can't be overloading .
5. we can say a New operator create a block(space) where the our program execute.
6. Create a boundary of the program.
7. Two program communication each other help of the object. The object who is created , I know very well NEW operator.

a simple program below used with new operator.

```
class Program
{
    int x = 20;
    public void pro1()
    {
       Console.WriteLine( this.x);

        Console.WriteLine("pr1 call");


    }
}
static class porgram2
{
  static  int x = 10;
    public static void pro2()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(    porgram2.x); //Not need a object 
        Console.WriteLine("pro2 call");
                                     // This keyword is not allowed.  

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        porgram2.pro2(); // no need a object created. 
        Program pr = new  Program();//Must be a created object. 
        pr.pro1();
        Program pr2 = new Program(); // i have many time of create a object.
        pr2.pro1();
```

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the question. What you are saying here seems to be correct, but it's not an answer to the question that was actually asked.